# Shir Hama'alos in "Barech"?

Tags: minhag, passover-seder-hagada, bentching

Among the many *hagada* versions in use at the *seder* I attended this year, some of them included *Shir Hama'alos* before *birkas hamazon* in the "*Barech*" section and others did not. Is there any reason to deviate from the [usual practice of saying it on holidays](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%A4%D7%90#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.9F_.D7.A7.D7.A4.D7.90_.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.98) on the night of the *seder*?

Comment: I'll do you one better: one of my Haggadot (a reprint of a 1784 Haggadah) started Barech at "Nevarech SheAchalnu MiSheLo".

Comment: The practice of recite שיר המעלות בשוב may be tied to a fear that Torah might not be learned during the meal. As we have learned the Maggid prior to eating and (presumably) continued to discuss it over the שלחן עורך, the recitation of the מזמור shouldn't be necessary

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt interesting, sounds like answerable material...

Comment: @רבותמחשבות, I don't have reasonable mekorot on hand, or I would've answered as such

Comment: @DoubleAA I have never seen that, but it fits interestingly in since there is a discussion about how of all meals, this one's _b'racha acharona_ needs the least invitation/introduction.

Answer (score 3):

[This Hebrew article on Shir Hamaalos](http://web.nli.org.il/sites/nlis/he/song/Pages/Articles/%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8_%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%91_%D7%94%27__%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9F_%D7%91%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%95%D7%98.aspx) gives me some thoughts on this that may answer the question:

Firstly, while this is a very widespread Minhag nowadays, it isn't all that old. Perhaps some of the Haggados that you were using were based on versions that were written prior to this custom being accepted in many communities. This would mean that there is no reason not to say it.

Secondly, the article seems to understand that the purpose of Shir Hamaalos is to remind us of the destruction of the Beis Hamikdash, but in a more positive, redemption-focused attitude:

> ...אמירת 'שיר המעלות' נועדה להזכיר לסועדים את החורבן גם אם אמנם מתוך תחושת גאולה אופטימית...

If so, on a night where we celebrate such Ge'ulah, it may be less appropriate to say it...

Comment: Good point about the provenance. The earliest (of 2) source the article mentions is the _Sh'nei Luchos Hab'ris_, so any publication printed or descended from something printed before 1630(?) or outside the (often mystical) influence thereof - not just _hagados_ - would be expected to not have _Shir Hama'alos_.